# Extract text in between two strings if a third string is also present in between those two strings- Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with two columns (time_stamp and message),as shown below:

**Example spark dataframe**

```
      message                                             time_stamp
irrelevant_text Startstring [ID: 1AB]                   2015-01-23 08:23:16
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 08:24:20
irrelevant_text mandatorystring ID [1AB]                2015-01-23 08:25:32
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 08:27:18
contributor XYZ_ABCD                                    2015-01-23 08:27:54
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 08:28:36
irrelevant_text endstring [ID: 1AB]                     2015-01-23 08:30:47
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 08:24:20
irrelevant_text Startstring [ID: 2BC]                   2015-01-23 10:05:16
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 10:24:20
contributor LMN_EFG_X                                   2015-01-23 10:27:21
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 10:28:34
irrelevant_text endstring [ID: 2BC]                     2015-01-23 10:30:47
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 10:50:20
irrelevant_text Startstring [ID: 3DE]                   2015-01-23 12:21:16
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 12:24:20
irrelevant_text mandatorystring ID [3DE]                2015-01-23 12:37:32
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 12:45:18
contributor PQRS_STU_wtx                                2015-01-23 12:47:05
some irrelevant text                                    2015-01-23 12:48:33
irrelevant_text endstring [ID: 3DE]                     2015-01-23 12:59:47
```

I am looking to extract contributor appeared in between **Startstring** and **endstring** if **mandatorystring** exists between **Startstring** and **endstring** and discarding the contributors if mandatorystring **doesn't exists** between Startstring and endstring. There may be multiple such instances in one Date.

**Expected Output:**

```
time_stamp                 contributor
2015-01-23 08:27:54         XYZ_ABCD                                    
2015-01-23 12:47:05       PQRS_STU_wtx
```

For reading the text file I used following command.

```
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferSchema", "false").schema(schema).option("delimiter", "\t").load('{}'.format(fileName))
```

Comment: Are these lines individual rows of the dataframe?

Comment: yes, They are individual rows of the spark dataframe with column headers as "message" and "time_stamp"

Comment: Is there a different way you could be reading / grouping the data beforehand? How are you controlling that the starting and ending string end up in the same executor?

Comment: This program will be written in Azure databricks and I think that Azure databricks handles this at their end. So, we do not have to think about that. This dataframe is created from a tab delimited text file. For reading the text file I used following command.  "df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferSchema", "false").schema(schema).option("delimiter", "\t").load('{}'.format(fileName))"

Comment: No, databricks wouldn't handle that. For example, all timestamps prior to noon could appears on executor 1, where you have a start string at 11. Then executor 2 has a corresponding end string at 1:00... Somewhere you need to group the rows together to ensure data isn't split

Comment: for the purpose of this question, lets assume that entire dataframe is executed by the same executor.

Comment: Sure. Do you have any attempt so far? Or are expecting someone to write for you?

Comment: I actually converted entire dataframe into one string and applied regex to extract. Its working fine but sometimes the databrick takes a long time if the dataset size is very large. I have the dataset of about 1TB volume. The pattern I used is:  "Startstring(?:(?!Startstring).)*?mandatorystring(?:(?!Startstring).)*?,['\s]*ID\s*:\s*([^',]*).*?endstring"

Comment: Right... If you're going to do that, then you shouldn't be using spark at all. On the other hand, like I said, you need to group the lines to find the corresponding ends of the starts, which that is one way to do it, but then you have no timestamps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226119/discussion-between-dataholic-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: My immediate suggestion would be to not use the CSV reader and instead use the HadoopRDD reader, but you have to write Java code for that. However, that's probably the most appropriate and fastest running method for the problem as it would appropriately split the data into the chunks you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the groups of messages that are valid (those containing "mandatory"), and get the messages containing "contributor" from the valid message groups.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'begin',
    F.last(
        F.when(F.col('message').rlike('Startstring'), F.col('time_stamp')), True
    ).over(Window.orderBy('time_stamp'))
).withColumn(
    'end',
    F.first(
        F.when(F.col('message').rlike('Endstring'), F.col('time_stamp')), True
    ).over(Window.orderBy('time_stamp').rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing))
).withColumn(
    'mandatory',
    F.sum(
        F.col('message').rlike('mandatory').cast('int')
    ).over(Window.partitionBy('begin', 'end'))
).filter(
    "mandatory >= 1 and message rlike 'contributor'"
).select(
    'time_stamp',
    F.regexp_extract('message', 'contributor (\S+)', 1).alias('contributor')
)

df2.show()
+-------------------+------------+
|         time_stamp| contributor|
+-------------------+------------+
|2015-01-23 08:27:54|    XYZ_ABCD|
|2015-01-23 12:47:05|PQRS_STU_wtx|
+-------------------+------------+
```

Comment: NOTE: This is a nice solution for small volume of data, but this solution cannot be run on databricks if you are using it for big data. It uses windows function which limits the worker node usage to 1, even if you have many worker nodes. I had to develop my own solution using SQL to use the parallelism in databricks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window` functions.

Try below code.

Import required libraries.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
```

Loading data into data frame.

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("/tmp/data/sample.csv")
```

```
df \
.withColumn("subMessage", \
    F.when(F.col("message").contains("Startstring"),F.lit("start"))\ 
    .when(F.col("message").contains("mandatorystring"),F.lit("mandatory")) \
    .when(F.col("message").contains("contributor"),F.regexp_replace(F.col("message"),"contributor ","")) \
    .when(F.col("message").contains("endstring"),F.lit("end"))\
) \
.filter(F.col("subMessage").isNotNull()) \
.withColumn("iscontributor",((F.lead(F.col("subMessage"),1).over(Window.orderBy(F.lit(1))) == "end") & (F.lag(F.col("subMessage"),1).over(Window.orderBy(F.lit(1))) == "mandatory"))) \
.filter(F.col("iscontributor") == True) \
.show()
```

Final Output.

```
+--------------------+-------------------+------------+-------------+
|             message|         time_stamp|  subMessage|iscontributor|
+--------------------+-------------------+------------+-------------+
|contributor XYZ_ABCD|2015-01-23 08:27:54|    XYZ_ABCD|         true|
|contributor PQRS_...|2015-01-23 12:47:05|PQRS_STU_wtx|         true|
+--------------------+-------------------+------------+-------------+
```